# Jquery modal window show only if input value lenght is more than 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code for showing modal window when i click enter on my keybord:

```
  $(".search-input").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      $('#screen').css({ opacity: 0.5, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()});
      $('#screen').show();
      $('#loading_modal').show();    
    }
  });
```

but i need to custom it so, that if input with class .search-input value is less than 3, i didn't show any modal window's...

I try so:

```
  $(".search-input").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      if($(".search-input").value.length > 2) {
        $('#screen').css({ opacity: 0.5, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()});
        $('#screen').show();
        $('#loading_modal').show();    
      }
    }
  });
```

but for some reasons it doesn't work(  How to solve my problem?

Comment: Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/132/ I think you need this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `trim()` to remove whitespace and `val()`

try this

```
  if($.trim($(this).val()).length > 2) {
      ......
```

Comment: no - didn't work, also i need to delete non english letters and spaces to compare

Comment: `value is less than 3` you mean the enter text value is less than three... or less than 3 characters ??

Comment: so: if i enter more or exact 3 characters i show modal, if string length is 0, 1, 2 i don't need to show it...

Comment: then did you try with length... ??

Comment: no.. any seletor should work.. unless you have many input with the same class in your docs

Answer (score 1):

This will basicly replace any text with nothing:

```
$(".search-input").value.replace(/{.*?}/g, '').length > 2
```

Try this instead:

```
$.trim($(this).val().replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '')).length > 2
```

If you ***really only*** want letters in the search string do this:

```
$(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '').length > 2
```

Comment: Then something else is probably wrong with your code, need more information.

Comment: don't take in mind replacing of letters, becouse clear $.trim($(".search-input").val()).length > 2 didn't work

Comment: That is really basic code, shouldn't be a problem with it. Set an ID on the search input and use that selector instead.